# powershell get-item in order to copy-item

Tags: powershell

I want to search within directories one file (it's only 1 file which is produced, so I found this , which does give me the fullpath , but I'd like to assign it to a variable in order to "copy-item" it later on.

```
get-childitem $out_folder -r | where {$_.extension -eq ".msi"} | % {
Write-host $_.Fullname
}
```

So I've tried

```
get-childitem $out_folder -r | where {$_.extension -eq ".msi"} | % {
$myFile =  $_.Fullname
}
```

but $myFile does not contain anything :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first example is outputting the path, give this a try:

```
$myFile =  get-childitem $out_folder -r | where {$_.extension -eq ".msi"} |
 % {$_.Fullname}
```